# How do I pass state to IonRouterLink in Ionic 7?

Tags: ionic-framework, location, state, routerlink, ionic7

I'm using ionic 7 and react 18.  I have this router link

```
              routerLink='/contact'
              style={{ color: 'blue', cursor: 'pointer', marginLeft: '4px' }}
            >
```

How would I add a state variable (prevPath) to the link such that on the component accessed by visiting the link, I can then access the state using

```
type ContactComponentProps = {
  contact: Contact | null
}
...
  const location = useLocation<LocationState>();
    ...
          const url = location.state?.prevPath || '/home';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of Ionic React, [`IonRouterLink`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/build-options#usage-with-standalone-based-applications) primarily facilitates navigation using properties like `href` for specifying the destination URL and `routerDirection` for the transition animation.

If you need to pass state to a route in a React application, you would typically use the [`Link` component](https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-router-passing-data-states-through-links/) from the [`react-router-dom` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom). That would allow you to pass a state via a `state` prop, and this state can be accessed in the target route using the [`useLocation` hook](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location).

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// your component code

<Link to="/your-route" state={{ yourStateData }}>Link Text</Link>
```

And in the target component, you can access this state with:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// your component code

const location = useLocation();
const stateData = location.state;
```